# JavaScript nested array not able to use values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, lua

I am working on a Telegram program for a game. Step1: I have to call the MYSQL to pull the data in lua. Step2: I have to send the table data to my NUI in my telegram.js file. Step3: I have to convert the string in to an array.

I have this in my telegram.js which is the exact layout of the data being pulled.

```
  var Atest = [
    (a1 = [7, 1, 'This is a test', 1, '05:30:35pm', '09/23/2021', 1]),
    (b1 = [7, 1, 'Test Test', 1, '05:40:35pm', '09/26/2021', 2]),
  ];
```

This works fine as it is in the .js file. When I bring a string over from my telegram.lua file I can split the data to an array console.log

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(Atest)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
0: 7, 1, This is a test, 1, 05:30:35pm, 09/23/2021, 1
1: "diff string ect..."
```

One of the issues I am having is the inner value will not register. Again it will work with this example because it is in my .js but when bring over a string I can not get the js to get the inner array to have an index.

Using `for k,v in pair do` is also not accurate when posting in order which wouldn't matter if I could get the string to convert to a full array.

The code that requires this in my menu program is as follows.

```
telegram.js

function newMessages(nTT) {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(nTT)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
    sleep(100);
    console.log(nTT);
    for (const [k, v] of nTT.entries()) {
      var split_date = v[5].split('/');
      var newb = document.createElement('a');
      var newb_i = document.createElement('input');
      newb_i.setAttribute('id', `checkbox_${k + 1}`);
      newb_i.setAttribute('class', 'checkbox');
      newb_i.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
      newb_i.setAttribute('value', 'value');
      newb_i.setAttribute('data-delete_tele_number', v[6]);
      newb.setAttribute('id', 'new_b');
      newb.setAttribute('data-id', v[0]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-new_old', v[1]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-message', v[2]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-to_id', v[3]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-time', v[4]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-date', v[5]);
      newb.setAttribute('data-tele_number', v[6]);
      newb.setAttribute('onclick', 'reply_click(this)');
      newb.innerHTML = `From ${v[0]} on ${split_date[0]}/${split_date[1]} # ${v[6]}`;
      document.getElementById('new_menu').appendChild(newb).prepend(newb_i);
    }
    check_checked();
    disable_tele_input();
  }
```

I am going to have to end up changing my value data structure as well since my way of using the for k, v loop to using the "id's" that are in my database to something like v[id] instead of calling v[0] in this example. This would be easy and is already in the string that is sent from lua but if I can get the string to register as an entire array with a "key" and "value" then everything I just built won't work lol.

I have spent many hours trying to find a way to bring the string inside js and reconstruct it so it is an ARRAY. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have tried to arr.push to a new array for each value, i have split() based on adding special "-" to deconstruct and rebuild. I have done a match using RegExp.

This is the actual data from my database.

```
MSYQL DB

INSERT INTO `telegram` (`id`, `new_old`, `message`, `to_id`, `time`, `date`, `tele_number`) VALUES
(7, 1, 'This is a test Message. Testing 123.', 1, '05:30:35PM', '09/23/2021', 1),
(5, 1, 'Test. For science.', 7, '05:30:35PM', '09/23/2021', 2),
(7, 0, 'herro', 7, '05:30:35PM', '09/23/2021', 3),
(7, 1, 'Hey', 4, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 4),
(7, 0, 'Bro', 7, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 5),
(7, 1, 'Brommblkdljf', 7, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 6),
(7, 1, 'test', 4, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 7),
(7, 1, 'bro this is a new messate', 1, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 8),
(7, 1, 'alskdjflsddlfkj', 7, '08:13:17PM', '09/23/2021', 9),
(7, 1, 'lets see if the whole thing works', 7, '04:56:27PM', '10/04/2021', 10),
(7, 1, 'bro lets try this again', 7, '05:05:23PM', '10/04/2021', 11);
```

This is the sort from lua

```
telegram_sv.lua

for k, v in ipairs(nTele) do
  print(k, json.encode(v))
  n[#n+1] = v
end
  newTele = json.encode(n)
  print(newTele)
```

```
telegram.js

 function n_string(nT) {
    nTS = nT.replace("[", "");
    nTS = nTS.replace("]", "");
    nTs = nTS.replace(",",", ")
    let regexp = /\{([^}]*)\}/g;
   nTT = nTS.match(regexp)
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(nTT)) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
    console.log(nTT[0]);
  }
...tons more code under... sends to newMessages(nTT) at some point...
```

I thank you all!

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have already figured out my mistake. I forgot to JSON.parse().

```
newTT = [];
   for ([k, v] of Object.entries(nTT)) {
    newTT.push(JSON.parse(v))
   }
```